# v-date-picker customize it and have today, last 7 days beside it

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi just got a question if this kind of thing is possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxu2P.png)

this is so far I have done.

```
<template>
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="landscape"
      label="Landscape"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-date-picker
      v-model="picker"
      landscape
    ></v-date-picker>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to give us more details. What exactly do you want?

Comment: the one in the image, is what I really want.. the code I paste is the one I'm using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `v-card`. It was challenging one and been looking for the answer all over, I was like crashing my head on it. The output would be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxZiw.png)

The complete code:

```
<template v-if="filters">
        <div class="d-flex justify-lg-space-between filter__activities">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="searchInText"
            outlined
            dense
            append-icon="fas fa-search"
            placeholder="Search"
          />

          <div class="px-2" />

          <v-select
            v-model="searchInSelect"
            append-icon="fas fa-chevron-down"
            item-color="lucky-point"
            placeholder="Category"
            outlined
            dense
            :items="types"
            :menu-props="{ bottom: true, offsetY: true }"
            class="lucky-point--text"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="filter__activities">
          <v-menu
            ref="menu1"
            v-model="menu1"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y
            bottom
            min-width="auto"
          >

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-text-field
                :value="computedDateFormatted"
                outlined
                dense
                placeholder="Select Date"
                append-icon="mdi-calendar"
                v-on="on"
              />
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="pa-2 py-16">
                  <div class="py-1">
                    <v-btn
                      plain
                      class="text-capitalize text-subtitle-1 mine-shaft--text filter__activities-active-btn"
                    >
                      Today
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>

                  <div class="py-1">
                    <v-btn
                      plain
                      class="text-capitalize text-subtitle-1 mine-shaft--text"
                    >
                      Last 7 days
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>

                  <div class="py-1">
                    <v-btn
                      plain
                      class="text-capitalize text-subtitle-1 mine-shaft--text"
                    >
                      Last 30 days
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>

                  <div class="py-1">
                    <v-btn
                      plain
                      class="text-capitalize text-subtitle-1 mine-shaft--text"
                    >
                      Last 90 days
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <span class="mx-2 mercury--bx-1"></span>

                <div>
                  <v-date-picker
                    v-model="date"
                    @input="menu1 = false"
                    flat
                    no-title
                    color="lucky-point"
                    width="392"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </v-card>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </template>
```